# Why can't I pipe find results into cp, but it works using exec?

Tags: bash, find, exec

I am using `find` to list files within multiple directories with a specific extension. I tried

```
find /path/to/encompassing/directory/ -d -name "*modified.tif" | xargs  cp Destination_Directory/
```

but it didn't work. Using

```
find /path/ -d -name "*modified.tif" -type f -exec cp {} Destination_Directory \;
```

works but I don't understand why xargs isn't working.

Comment: Are you trying to copy files or directories? It's unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the directories but only containing specific files.

Comment: Did you edit the question and accidentally delete parts of it?

Comment: And is `- name` (with a blank) a typo in the second command?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, sorry. But nothing else is a typo. Now that the exec flag worked, I realized I need to copy the files retaining the directory structure. I'm trying to use ditto instead of cp.

Comment: `rsync` would likely be better if you need exact copies..

Comment: I was asking because you're saying "Using [command]" and then nothing. Feels like "...works, but why?" or similar is missing.

Comment: Fixed. Any idea how to copy their encompassing directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write

```
find -name '*modified.tif' | xargs cp directory
```

then that's the same as writing

```
cp directory file1modified.tif file2modified.tif
```

(or whatever filenames matched), which is the wrong way around, because `xargs` by default appends arguments.

```
find -name '*modified.tif' -exec cp {} directory \;
```

is the same as

```
cp file1modified.tif directory
cp file2modified.tif directory
```

which is what you want.

You can achieve the same with `xargs` by using

```
xargs -I{} cp {} directory
```

to specify where in the command you want to use the argument, but that implies that only one file at a time will be copied (because `-I` implies `-L1`).

To avoid calling `cp` once per file, you can use the `-t` option for `cp` so the files to be copied can be appended to the end of the command (requires GNU `cp`):

```
find -name '*modified.tif' | xargs cp -t directory
```

which is equivalent to

```
cp -t directory file1modified.tif file2modified.tif
```

or better, taking care of blanks in filenames,

```
find -name '*modified.tif' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t directory
```

Alternatively, without `xargs`:

```
find -name '*modified.tif' -exec cp -t directory {} +
```

where `-exec {} +` makes sure to invoke `cp` as few times as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` passes each word from its standard input as the *last* argument to `cp`, not the first. As a result, you are trying to run the series of commands

```
cp Destination_Directory/ foo
cp Destination_Directory/ bar
# etc
```

If you are using GNU `cp`, you can fix this simply by using the `-t` option to specify that `Destination_Directory` is the *target*, rather than a source.

```
... | xargs cp -t Destination_Directory
# cp -t Destination_Directory foo
# cp -t Destination_Directory bar
# etc
```

You *might* be able to use the `-I` option in `xargs` to make it use the incoming file name as the first argument:

```
... | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' Destination_Directory
```

however, this makes a lot of assumptions about the names `find` will produce. (No leading or trailing whitespace, and no newlines in the file names.) (For that matter, `xargs` *without* `-I` is treating each whitespace-delimited *word* from its input as a separate argument for a call to `cp`.) In general, you should not try to use the output of `find` programmatically. Stick with its `-exec` primary instead.

Your code

```
find /path/ -d -name "*modified.tif" -type f -exec cp {} Destination_Directory \;
```

is the right way to go. No shell is involved, so each file name is passed *as is* as the first argument to `cp`.

Comment: `xargs` should be able to handle filename/directories with spaces or newlines using the following I would imagine: `... -print0 | xargs -0I{} cp {} dest`

Comment: It can, but neither `-print0` nor `-0` are standard. There's very little reason to use `xargs` at all in place of `-exec`. (I realize my suggestion to use `cp -t` is also non-standard, and *still* doesn't work for all possible outputs from `find`, but it addresses the primary issue of out-of-order arguments to `cp`.)

Answer (score -1):

I don't use xargs, but I think it should work like this :

```
cp `find  /path/to/encompassing/directory/ -d  -name "*modified.tif"` Destination_Directory/
```

No need for a pipe then.