# How to transform -exec to xargs for better performance in UNIX SHELL?

Tags: shell, unix, xargs, cp

Sorry, a very simple question. How can I transform the following working code to copy all JSON files to the parent folder, using xargs? The motivation is to work on a lot of files (150K files).

```
find . -regex '.*\.json' -exec cp {} ../ \;
```

I tried the following:

```
find . -regex '.*\.json' | xargs cp ../
```

Is this a correct command?
Anyway, I got an error:

```
cp: .//abc.json is not a directory
```

This error is not the primary question here, but I just wanted to get know-how of this kind of operation. I heard that xargs is faster and efficient.
Thanks!

Comment: find's `-exec ... {} +` means there's no reason to use xargs.

Comment: Though you'll have the same problem. If using GNU `cp` (You tagged unix, not linux, so maybe not?), `find . -name "*.json" -exec cp -t dest-directory/ {} +` is the usual approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I pipe find results into cp, but it works using exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228307/why-cant-i-pipe-find-results-into-cp-but-it-works-using-exec)

Comment: I would try `find . -name '*.json' | while read -r f; do echo cp -i "$f" ..; done`.  Remove `echo` to run.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks a lot! This is the case where there are thousands of files, hence the question. So, my impression was to use xargs, but I am open for new approach.

Comment: I changed my question slightly to explain my goal.

Comment: please clarify "parent directory". If `find` is run in directory `a` and there is file `a/b/c/f.json` does it move to `a/..` or to `a/b` ? Can there be collisions? (eg. `a/b/f.json` already exists)